# I cannot load windows plugins in carla

Tags: wine, plugins, ubuntu-studio

When I load windows plugins (vst2, vst3, as dlls) into Carla, I get an error message stating *"Timeout while waiting for a response from plugin-bridge
(or the plugin crashed on initialization?)"*.  I tried reinstalling the plugins, but this did not work.  I have found the same behavior with several plugins.  I have installed all of the carla bridges, and have set Carla to use the bridges.  I am running Ubuntu 21.10, with Ardour and Ubuntu Studio supplied Carla.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I recently updated Ubuntu (Studio) from 21.10 to 22.04.  I can now load windows plugins into Carla.  I'm thinking that the version of wine in Ubuntu Studio 21.10 (5.03) was the problem; Ubuntu Studio 22.04 has wine version 6.